# Synchronizing Angular tasks

Tags: angular

I have and application where the first thing I need to do is fetch data from the server (mainly drop down list options). The fetching is done using HTTP.GET.
The first thing I do in app.module.ts in ngOninit I call the loading service.
Meanwhile the rest of the application starts and the first screen appears without the data from the database. Writting some debug logs I see that the data is fetched a few seconds after the first screen appears.
I have a few options I can do but I don't know how to implement.
1. Stop the applicaion from starting untill the data is fetched from the DB.
2. Send an event from the fetching routine to the display module to let it know that new data has arrived.
3. Anything you can think of.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Moshik

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Route Resolver to ensure the data is loaded prior to the component being loaded:

https://www.positronx.io/angular-7-route-resolvers/

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your dropdowns with empty array [ ]; once data comes from server, it should automatically populate your UI controls...

(or)

if you do not want to display your UI controls with empty data, then you could add an ***ngIf** and display your controls when data is available and remove otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

After a few testing the simplest solution was using ngAfterContentChecked.
In this routine I reload the arrays that are bound to the template. The data for these arrays comes from the DB. After the reload the template displays them so problem solved.

Moshik